# Objective-C: Convert performSelector to Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have some code that I got from a book that uses performSelectorOnMainThread.  I am finding that it is freezing the app in some cases and want to change it to a background thread using GCD:

This is my code:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Should changing it to GCD background be as simple as

```
[self  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
    (fetchData:) withObject:data
}];
```

That is currently throwing error expected ']'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. It needs to be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self fetchData:data];
});
```

Note that `dispatch_async` is a function call, not a method call. It takes a block as the 2nd parameter. The code inside the block is where you put the actual code you want called on the background.